# Got ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using *ngFor and ContentChildren

Tags: javascript, angular, exception

I have tabs and tab components:

tabs.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cl-tabs',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
    styleUrls: ['tabs.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        if (0 < this.tabs.length) {
            this.activate(this.tabs.first);
        }
    }

    activate(activatedTab: TabComponent) {
        this.tabs.forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
        activatedTab.active = true;
    }
}
```

tab.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cl-tab',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
    styleUrls: ['tab.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TabComponent {
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() @HostBinding('class.is-active') active: boolean = false;
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<cl-tabs>
    <cl-tab *ngFor="let item of items" [title]="item.name">
        <any-component [item]="item"></any-component>
    </cl-tab>
</tabs>
```

When tabs are created using *ngFor an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError is thrown.

cdRef.detectChanges(), as suggested in many cases, doesn't help.

Error dissapears if:

- tabs are created statically; or
- HostBinding is removed from "active" field; or
- setTimeout is applied to ngAfterContentInit.

Why does the error dissapear in the first two cases?
Is there any better alternative to setTimeout in that particular case?

**UPDATE:** Reproduced the error in plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/ZUOvf6NXCj2JOLTwbsYU/

Comment: hey, what is the exact wording of the error? that's a quite complex setup

Comment: @Maximus ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. The setup is pretty complex. If you setup a plunker with the reproducible problem I'll take a look

Comment: @Maximus Updated question with a link to plunker with the error.

Comment: _tabs are created statically_ - what do you mean statically?

Comment: @Maximus I mean not using ngFor and writing cl-tab 3 times and passing items[0], 1 and 2.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought, just posted the answer, it's definitely not easy to understand, you have to posses a good knowledge of internals and at least have read and understood the articles I mention in the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand the answer you have to read and understand these two articles first:

- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)
- [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Let's look at the following template of `App` component:

```
<cl-tabs>
  <cl-tab *ngFor="let item of items" [title]="item.name"></cl-tab>
</cl-tabs>
```

Here you have content projection and embedded views (created by `ngFor`).
 
There are two points that are essential to understand:

- projected nodes are registered and stored as part of the existing view, not the view they are projected into
- embedded views are checked before the `ngAfterContentInit` is triggered.

Now, bearing the above points in mind for you particular setup

```
export class App {
  items = [
    {name: "1", value: 1},
    {name: "2", value: 2},
    {name: "3", value: 3},
  ];
}
```

You can imaging the following structure of the AppComponent view:

```
AppView.nodes: [
   clTabsComponentView
   ngForEmbeddedViews: [
      ngForEmbeddedView<{name: "1", value: 1}>
      ngForEmbeddedView<{name: "2", value: 2}>
      ngForEmbeddedView<{name: "3", value: 3}>
```

And when change detection is triggered for the AppView here is the order of operations:

1) Check clTabsComponentView

2) Check all views in ngForEmbeddedViews. 
Here the value `active = false` is remembered for each view.

3) Call `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle hook.
Here you update the `active = true`. So during verification phase Angular will detect the difference and report the error.

> Why does the error dissapear in the first two cases?
>   Now sure what you mean by `statically`. If you mean not using `*ngFor` then there will be no error since then each TabComponentView will be child view, not an embedded view. And child views are processed after the `ngAfterContentChecked` lifecycle hook.

If you remove `@HostBinding` then there's nothing for Angular to check in the component and `active` value is not remembered - thus no verification and no check.

> cdRef.detectChanges(), as suggested in many cases, doesn't help.

You need to call change detection on the AppComponent for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation! So, in the end, i guess, there's no better workaround for this error than timeout in my case? Or maybe there's something wrong architectually with my approach?

Comment: tell me what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make some basic tab functionality. Primarily it's based on these tuts: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html, https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/learning-ng2-creating-tab-component/

Comment: @VladislavNikolayev, I see... complex functionality, unfortunately don't have  time to look into it in details

Answer (score 3):

I'm so late. Anyways.

I did add an empty template to provide to ngTemplateOutlet a value meanwhile de each template is ready.

```
<div class="stepper--stages">
  <div class="stepper--single-stage" *ngFor="let stage of stages">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="stage.templateRef || placeholder"></ng-container>
  </div>
  <ng-template #placeholder></ng-template>
</div>
```

**Edit**:

I'm using a simple OR operator in the template. The interesting thing here is: Why this snippet works properly when it has been rendered by the Angular app later in the app's flow vs when the hole Angular app is reloaded by the window. In the second case, Angular seems like it's taking the #placeholder directly instead templateOutlet.

Comment: Attention: it works fine when the route which contains this snippet is called more later in your app's flow. If this snippet is rendered immediately after the window reloads, then Angular will take #placeholder instead the ngTemplateOutlet.

Comment: Greate solution, it work but can u explaine?

Comment: @AndrzejKrawczuk I edited my answer. I don't know why this is working different in the two scenarios I explained above. I definitively know this is related with the rendering flows of Angular...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are changing value after they have been checked by angulars changedetection. Here is the problem:

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    if (0 < this.tabs.length) {
        this.activate(this.tabs.first);
    }
}
```

`setTimeout` would be the best solution as it creates a macrotask. An other solution would be to trigger changedetection again, but this will call it for your whole application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still don't get why the error dissapears in the first two cases with static tabs or no host binding. Do you have any clue on that? As for change detection, do you mean running cdRef.detectChanges()?